# NumberFormatException from hex number

Tags: java, hex, numberformatexception

In my code I have

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("f8004896",16);
```

when I run the program it throws a `NumberFormatException`

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "f8004896"
```

What am I doing wrong? This seems relatively straightforward but its not working.

Comment: What value is `f8004896` in decimal?

Comment: what do you mean? like its decimal value?

Comment: Yes, does its value fit in an `int`. It's just easier to think in decimal.

Comment: well, im stupid, it doesnt. thanks

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Why is it easier to think in decimal?  I find it much easier to remember that the biggest integer is 0x7fffffff than 2147... something.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ok, IMO. I just haven't worked with HEX values at all.

Comment: The NumberFormatException is kind of misleading when it comes to something like this. The number is formatted correctly it should be like BitwiseOverflowException or something lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
long i = Long.parseLong("f8004896", 16);
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Output:

```
4160768150
2147483647
```

Answer (score 1):

Decimal value for `f8004896` is `4160768150` and it's more than 2^31-1 (upper limit for int type). So you should use `long` instead: `Long.parseLong()`

Comment: You made a mistake in "upper limit for long". I have edited your answer.

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev yep, it was a typo indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Do not mention it. And thank you for your understanding!